# How to write a derived perf event in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

I want to implement a new derived Linux perf event, X in the kernel space. A user-space application can *perf_event_open* the derived event and read the derived metrics.

At the kernel level, the derived perf event will use multiple hardware events to monitor and collect performance data. Based on the collected data, the derived event will generate a new metric. In other words, X = func (hw-event-1, hw-event-2, ...). The func will be implemented in kernel space.

I searched the perf list but it seems that all the derived metrics (Kernel_Utilization, Page_Walks_Utilization etc.) are written in the user-space perf tool. Can you point me to some kernel code that implements a derived metric in kernel-space?

Comment: Can you give some example of event sets for your derived events? Do you want sampling (like in `perf record`) or counting (like in `perf stat`) for these events? If perf tool implements derived events in user-space tool, this may be the correct way. There is another [library PAPI](https://bitbucket.org/icl/papi/wiki/Home) which uses `perf_event_open` syscall and implement derived events in user-space too.

Comment: Yes. I will use sampling along with other events. I understand that it is natural to implement the derived metric in user-space. However, for a specific scenario, I would like to put it in the kernel space.

Comment: You can't use sampling with derived events based on hardware counters. Hardware PMU unit generates interrupt on counter overflow, so perf_events kernel subsystems sets the counter to some large negative value like -1000000 and set up this counter channel to count some event (like retired instructions or cpu cycles). When this counter is incremented from -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFF) to 0 interrupt is generated, perf sample event is dumped into ring buffer and counter is reset back into -1000000. Hardware PMU can't count several events into one counter. Can you give examples of hw-event-1 hw-event-2?